# How to fix 'ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list' error in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove the 'Maths, 76' from my list 'Marks' but it keeps throwing up:

```py
line 2, in <module>
    Marks.remove("Maths, 76")
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

I have tried changing the code to have Maths as a separate entity but it has not worked.

```py
Marks = ['Amy', 'Jones', 'English', 72, 'Maths', 76, 'Computer Science', 96]
Marks.remove("Maths, 76")
print(Marks)
```

I believe the output should just be the list without the variable, but it just outputs the full list.

Comment: Your list doesn't contain `"Maths, 76"`. It contains `"Maths"` and `76`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.remove` takes a single argument, which is the item you want to remove.

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

> list.remove(x)
>   Remove the first item from the list whose value is equal to x. It raises a ValueError if there is no such item.

But `"Maths, 76"` is not an element in your list, hence you get the error `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`
So you want to remove each element one at a time

```
Marks = ['Amy', 'Jones', 'English', 72, 'Maths', 76, 'Computer Science', 96]
Marks.remove("Maths")
Marks.remove(76)
print(Marks)
```

Or use a for loop

```
Marks = ['Amy', 'Jones', 'English', 72, 'Maths', 76, 'Computer Science', 96]

for item in ["Maths", 76]:
    Marks.remove(item)

print(Marks)
```

The output will be

```
['Amy', 'Jones', 'English', 72, 'Computer Science', 96]
```

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
Marks = ['Amy', 'Jones', 'English', 72, 'Maths', 76, 'Computer Science', 96]
Marks.remove("Maths, 76")
```

you will get this error because the exact string "Maths, 76" is not in the list.

The string "Maths" is in the list and so is the number 76, so these can both be removed separately:

```
Marks.remove("Maths")
Marks.remove(76)
```

You could pair up the entries, assuming a first and second name, into tuples like this:

```
>>> list(zip(Marks[0::2], Marks[1::2]))
[('Amy', 'Jones'), ('English', 72), ('Maths', 76), ('Computer Science', 96)]
```

Then you could remove `('Maths', 76)`.

Or you can make a dictionary comprehension from your list:

```
>>> {k:v for k,v in zip(Marks[0::2], Marks[1::2])}
{'Amy': 'Jones', 'English': 72, 'Maths': 76, 'Computer Science': 96}

>>> lookup = {k:v for k,v in zip(Marks[0::2], Marks[1::2])}
>>> lookup['Maths']
76
```

The remove an item, use `pop`:

```
>>> lookup.pop('Maths')
76
>>> lookup
{'Amy': 'Jones', 'English': 72, 'Computer Science': 96}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to remove the string `"Maths, 76"` which does not exist in the list.

Either you do:

```
Marks.remove("Maths")
Marks.remove(76)
```

Either you change your list like this:

```
Marks = ['Amy', 'Jones', 'English', 72, "Maths, 76", 'Computer Science', 96]
```

> NB: As far I understand what you are trying to do, you really should consider **using [dictionaries](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) instead of lists** for such a matter.

Example:

```
marks = {'first_name': 'Amy', 'name': 'Jones', 'English': 72, 'Maths': 76, 'Computer Science': 96}
del marks['Maths'] # to remove the Maths entry
```

Answer (score 0):

You face this error when the element does not exist in the list. I think the best way is to use if/else in a list comprehension.

For example:

```
Marks = ['Amy', 'Jones', 'English', 72, 'Maths', 76, 'Computer Science', 96]
Remove_result = [i for i in Marks if i != "Maths, 76"]
Remove_result
out[1].  ['Amy', 'Jones', 'English', 72, 'Maths', 76, 'Computer Science', 96]
```

`Remove_result` is not different from `Marks`, because  `"Maths, 76"` does not exist in `Marks`

**Note:** You cannot use `[Marks.remove(i) for i in Marks if i == "Maths, 76"]`, because it returns `[]`. The reason non of iterations can meet the `if` condition.